# Axios GET not including params in Nuxt template

Tags: api, axios, nuxt.js

I want to pass an id to axios so that I can switch url dynamically.

My axios request in my template is as follows:

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/', {
      params: {
        id: 1
      }
    })
    return { data }
  }
```

The request being passed to my api is:

```
GET /api/?id=1
```

but I need

```
GET /api/1
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the asyncData function is called once when the page is loaded. I am still no wiser as to why it does not accept params in the way outlined in the docs and numerous tutorials, but it would not refresh the page because it is never called again.

To refresh the page data with a new api call, you need to return the axios promise from within the methods part of the export. The code below does the axios get request first, then adds or subtracts 1 from the id with plus and minus functions.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Weather'
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return { counter: 1 }
  },
  methods: {
    plus: function(counter, data, datalength) {
      this.counter += 1
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/' + this.counter).then(res => {
        console.log(this.counter)
        console.log(res.data)
        return (this.data = res.data)
      })
    },
    minus: function(counter, data) {
      if (this.counter >= 2) {
        this.counter -= 1
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/' + this.counter).then(res => {
          console.log(this.counter)
          console.log(res.data)
          return (this.data = res.data)
        })
      } else {
        this.counter = 1
      }
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ params, counter }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/1')
    return { data }
  }
}
</script>
```

If anybody wants to elaborate or post a better solution, please go ahead - but I'm posting this because I searched so many tutorials and nothing worked until I found a way to interpret the documentation, which is certainly not beginner-friendly.